# Почему код парсера возвращает NoneType со страницы. После десятой итерации возвращается тип NoneType. Почему так?

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

host = 'https://coinmarketcap.com'
headers = {'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.174 YaBrowser/22.1.3.850 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
               'accept': '*/*'
               }

def get_html(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response.text

def write_csv(data):
    with open('data.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow( [data['name'],
                          data['symbol'],
                          data['price'],
                          data['link']
                         ])

def get_data(response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')
    trs = soup.find('table').find('tbody').find_all('tr')
    #print(len(trs))
    count = 0
    for tr in trs:
        #if tr != None: #count <=9: # сделал ограничение потому что страница не прогружается и
        # после 10 значения tr пустая и метод find выдаёт ошибку.
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        link = host + tds[2].find('a').get('href')#_text().split()
        name = tds[2].find('div', class_='sc-16r8icm-0').find('p', class_='sc-1eb5slv-0').text
        #print(name)
        symbol = tds[2].find('p', class_='sc-1eb5slv-0 gGIpIK coin-item-symbol').text
        price = tds[3].find('span').text
        data = { 'name' : name,
                 'symbol' : symbol,
                 'price' : price,
                 'link' : link
                }
        print(data)
        #write_csv(data)
        #count += 1

def main():
    html = get_html(host)
    get_data(html)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: переменная name получает со страницы ответ как NoneType после десятой итерации в цикле. Первые десять итераций работают хорошо, все методы find() отрабатывают правильно, а после десятого шага уже нет. Почему так, подскажите?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЯкутин это значит, что вместе с request сервер отдает только 10 строк таблицы, а остальные динамически подгружаются по мере прокрутки. Это можно проверить: удаляешь куки этого сайта, заходишь в нее как в первый раз и резко крутишь вниз. Пока не подгрузилась, можно увидеть пустые строрки. Для таких динамических сайтов нужно использовать selenium, а не request

Comment: Я думал что можно сделать это с помощью requests и  BeautifulSoup. Silenium я ещё не изучил. Благодарю